# How to swap 2 numeric numbers of unknown exact type, via two void pointer parameters?

Tags: c

I need to write a function that replaces 2 "numeric numbers", of otherwise unknown type.

I don't know the exact type and I can only use 2 parameters.

So this is what I have tried:

```
void swap(void *p1, void *p2)
{
    char p;
    char * q1 = (char *)p1;
    char * q2 = (char *)p2;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(long double); i++)
    {
        p = q1[i];
        q1[i] = q2[i];
        q2[i] = p;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
double a = 100123000000.2;
double b = 100065450000.3;
printf("a: %1f, b: %1f\n", a, b);
swap(&a, &b)
printf("a: %1f, b: %1f\n", a, b);
```

This works fine but my question is what if my `number` is bigger then `long double` (or there is no one..)
Is my solution OK?

Comment: What if it's *smaller*?

Comment: *2 numeric number* - you mean "binary number"?

Comment: i also try it with int and this works

Comment: @secs ago: no, just any number (same type)

Comment: *It works* by sheer luck. Try a more complicated program.

Comment: I don't this is possible in the general case, without knowing the type or size of the numbers. Is this an interview question? Are you sure it has a solution?

Comment: There's no good way to do this without passing the size of the inputs as a third parameter (like with `qsort`, for example).  Otherwise you're just guessing, which is guaranteed to cause mayhem at some point.  If you want to cheat, you can create a global that stores the size and reference that in the function, but that's a bad approach.

Comment: This is homework

Comment: Then, don't paraphrase the actual task but repeat it verbatim. Also, be prepared to answer that a solution can not be given, with a sufficient justification, of course.

Comment: The code does not have any `long double` and you have misread the book: `%1f` (one-eff) should be `%lf` (ell-eff). However the `double` type only needs `%lf` when its address is passed to `scanf` function family. The `printf` function family promotes `float` arguments to `double` and the `%f` format is good.

Comment: It's possible that you're supposed to use `_Generic` to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This works fine but my question is what if my number is bigger (?)
>   Is my solution is OK ?

Code will have trouble unless it knows the exact size.  So, no, OP's solution is not OK.
Somehow `void swap()` needs to know the size of the data to swap.

> i can only use 2 parameters.

Code can cheat and put all the data into **1** argument as a *compound literal*, since C99.

```
typedef struct {
  void *a;
  void *b;
  size_t sz;
} swap_T;

// Only 1 parameter!!
void swap(swap_T sw) {
  unsigned char * q1 = sw.a;
  unsigned char * q2 = sw.b;
  while (sw.sz > 0) {
    sw.sz--;
    unsigned char p = q1[sw.sz];
    q1[sw.sz] = q2[sw.sz];
    q2[sw.sz] = p;
  }
}

int main(void) {
  double a = 100123000000.2;
  double b = 100065450000.3;
  printf("a: %g, b: %g\n", a, b);
  swap(((swap_T ) { &a, &b, sizeof a } ));  // Compound literal
  printf("a: %g, b: %g\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
a: 1.00123e+11, b: 1.00065e+11
a: 1.00065e+11, b: 1.00123e+11
```

Code could wrap the `swap(((swap_T ) { &a, &b, sizeof a } ))` in a macro that looks like a function call of 2

```
#define SWAP(a,b) (swap(((swap_T ) { &(a), &(b), sizeof (a) } )))
...
SWAP(a,b);
```

As long as `a` is not an expression with a  *variable logic array* (VLA) and with side-effects, the macro should work fine.

Of course, best if `a,b` are the same type.

Comment: Interesting that your `swap()` function modifies the `size_t sz;` member of the `struct` passed, which of course won't affect the *source* of what was passed.

Answer (score 2):

Your program should try to retrieve `sizeof` of its argument to know how many bytes to swap - perhaps as a third argument - you have no way of telling otherwise how big an argument is. With current function you will overwrite memory which will end up badly - especially in a bigger program. For example, consider a following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    swap(&a[0], &a[4]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Which will return 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4 - which clearly isn't expected - only 0th and 4th array elements should have been swapped.

It's possible to hide getting size behind a macro if needed.

```
#define SWAP(a, b) swap(&(a), &(b), sizeof(a))
```

Comment: I cannot use third argument

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, though.

Comment: Also, `sizeof` is a compile-time operator, and can't possibly be useful to determine what pointer type is passed to a function at runtime.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker Re: "sizeof  ... can't possibly be useful to determine what pointer type is passed".  To swap, the type of the pointer is not important.  The size of the objects are important and that can be found with `sizeof`.  Otherwise unclear about your concern.

Comment: `sizeof(p)` inside a function that takes void pointer argument p will give you the size of the pointer. If you try sizeof(*p) it give you an error. There's no way to get the size of the thing pointed to unless you commit to it at compile time. (Or use C11 _Generic as suggested).